# R: Frequency Table on Unique Rows in a Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, frequency

I have a dataframe that looks like the following, where many are redundant rows. I'd like to collapse the dataframe so that there are only unique rows, but there is another variable `weight` that shows the number of times a unique row showed up.

A snippet of my dataframe:

```
from    to 
6140690 6141500
6140430 6140428
6141450 6140428
6141450 6140428
6140430 6141450
6140430 6141450
```

Desired output:

```
from    to      weight
6140690 6141500  1
6140430 6140428  1
6141450 6140428  2
6140430 6141450  2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an R base approach

```
 merge(unique(df), data.frame(table(df)))
     from      to Freq
1 6140430 6140428    1
2 6140430 6141450    2
3 6140690 6141500    1
4 6141450 6140428    2
```

Here's a dplyr approach using `count`:

```
  count(df, from, to, name="weight")
         from      to weight
    1 6140430 6140428      1
    2 6140430 6141450      2
    3 6140690 6141500      1
    4 6141450 6140428      2
```

Comment: This approach only counts the number of times "from" is unique. I've updated the example dataset a little bit, but ideally I would prefer to tabulate the times "from" AND "to" are unique

Comment: @Itong I edited my answer using your updated data.